# Azure B2C refresh token issues after revoke session due to Skew

Tags: azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy, azure-ad-b2c

I am following the details from the recent update to the policy start pack: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack

There appears to be a floor (or so I think) in the process.
I have tried to details the working and non working flow.

Is the 5 minute skew really necessary or am I missing something in my approach.

Thanks
Nigel.

--- Working ---

1. Request refresh token: refreshTokenIssuedOnDateTime = 13:10
2. Revoke session: refreshTokensValidFromDateTime = 13:20
3. Request new refresh token at 13:30:
   AssertRefreshTokenIssuedLaterThanValidFromDate correctly throw error as refreshTokensValidFromDateTime (13:20) > refreshTokenIssuedOnDateTime (13:10) (with 5 minute skew)

--- Not working ---

1. Request refresh token: refreshTokenIssuedOnDateTime = 13:10
2. Revoke session: refreshTokensValidFromDateTime = 13:12
3. Request new refresh token at 13:30:
   AssertRefreshTokenIssuedLaterThanValidFromDate does NOT throw an error refreshTokensValidFromDateTime (13:12) == refreshTokenIssuedOnDateTime (13:10) (with 5 minute skew)
   refreshTokenIssuedOnDateTime = 13:10
4. Request new refresh token at 15:00:
   AssertRefreshTokenIssuedLaterThanValidFromDate does NOT throw an error refreshTokensValidFromDateTime (13:12) < refreshTokenIssuedOnDateTime (13:30) (with 5 minute skew)
   refreshTokenIssuedOnDateTime = 15:00
5. Same as 4 as new refresh tokens always later than refreshTokensValidFromDateTime

To sum up it would appear that if I revoke the session within 5 minutes of the refresh token being issued then I will fall into the non working flow.